# How to create table from model classes from another directory in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python

This is my flask project directory structure,

```
src/models-> UserModel.py
          -> PassengerModel.py
src/run.py
```

and this `run.py` file contains the database connection object,

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_restful import Resource

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///appDB.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some-secret-string'
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'jwt-secret-string'
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS'] = ['access', 'refresh']
app.config['JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES'] = False

CORS(app)
db  = SQLAlchemy(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)

db.create_all()

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()

api = Api(app)

from src.models import UserModel, PassengerModel, DriverModel, OwnerModel, 
                       VehicleModel, TripPlanModel, TripStatusModel,PickupLocationsModel, 
                       WaypointsModel, DriverFeedbackModel, PassengerFeedbackModel
```

once the all these models inside one file, `db.create_all()` method works fine and creates the database file.

But when all the model classes inside the models directory and even after imports it to `run.py` file `db.create_all()` method is not working.

How can I create DB from models in a different directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

File structure:

```
src/models -> UserModel.py
           -> PassengerModel.py
           -> __init__.py 
  /__init__.py
```

src/run.py

Import models:

```
try:
    from src.models.usermodel import User
    from src.models.passengermodel import Passenger
    print('Models imported')
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
```

Hope that helps you. Cheers

PS: Probably you will need to put the imports for the models at the bottom of your file before the following:

```
Imports ...

...
your code
...

*** models imports here ***

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```